# How to ping a server using Ajax in Laravel every 5 minutes?

Tags: ajax, laravel, asynchronous, ping

I have a HTML table full of server IP addresses, and I want to ping them them every 5 minutes to check if the server is alive (and eventually highlight table rows depending if the server is dead/alive).

Currently I'm using Ajax with a 5 minute interval which calls a method in my controller:

```
var checkSims = function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:  '/checkSimStatus',
    success: function(msg) {
        onlineSims = msg['online'];
        offlineSims = msg['offline'];

        console.log(onlineSims);
        console.log(offlineSims);
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('false');
    }
    });

}

var interval = 1000 * 60 * 1; // where X is your every X minutes
setInterval(checkSims, interval);
```

However, this is not asynchronous and while this controller method is pinging the IPs the webserver cannot serve requests.

I've read about Laravel's queue system but I'm not sure this would suit me as I need one specific page to trigger the job, and would need to use JS to highlight table rows.

Comment: I would use Laravel's Queue functionality. Add each IP to the queue every 5 minutes and let the queue worker process them in the background.

Comment: @Joe how could I then highlight the table rows of the IPs that are dead/alive? This is why I wanted to use Ajax. I'm not sure how to connect Laravel's queue system with Ajax

Comment: That doesn't sound right. There's no limitation to a single request served at a time unless you're using the built-in PHP server or a badly configured webserver.

Comment: Laravel also supports broadcast events on websockets, but you could just do what you're doing now and update the page on an interval. The queue system is not really related to how you would display the data. It's all in the laravel documentation.

Answer (score -1):

@f7n if you have done it with ajax, how will it work if that page where HTML table with IP address not open in a browser?
I think you must use `cron job` on a server. Also, if you use VPS (Linux) or something else you can write simple code with bash shell script and run it on the daemon. Also, you can create simple code like below, create `php script` where it will parse (grab) page with HTML table of IP addresses and ping server.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Press [CTRL+C] to stop.."

while true
  do
    php parse_and_ping.php
  sleep 300
done
```

`sleep 300` is mean, It will work every 5 minutes. Just save It on `.sh` file (run_shell.sh) and run It on a terminal or on the daemon of Linux server.